# datepicker2 not pick days before datepicker1

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

Hello I have two datepicker:
`$("#dat1").datepicker` and `$("#dat2").datepicker`

Both return correct date in textbox. I want to do, when I click dat2, I can't choise days before dat1. First day if I choise is dat1+ 7 / next week. How can I do?

example: textbox1 = 05/12/2013
         textbox2 = not before 12/12/2013

My onselect:  `onSelect: function (date) { var d = new Date(date);});`

Comment: Take a look at this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: @Anton awesome example

Comment: Good. But what can I do if this is not selectedDate but date. This is my onselect: `onSelect: function (date {
                    var d = new Date(date);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/JBrvn/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            var x = selectedDate.split('/');
            var d = new Date(x[0] + ',' + x[1] + ',' + x[2]);
            var res = d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7);
            var dateMsg = (d.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + d.getDate() + '/' + d.getFullYear();
            console.log(dateMsg);
            $("#to").removeClass('hasDatepicker').datepicker({
                minDate: dateMsg
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: don't work. i can't click on textbox and choose. Only in ´$("#from").datepicker´ put this code?.

Comment: What can I do if i have date format dd.mm.yy I change datemsg sequence.

Comment: Nice. But how I change on this write: dd.mm.yy . To datepicker write with / and month on first place.

Comment: How #to datepicker select last day on week in this code. Sorry but I'm new here.  (http://jsfiddle.net/JBrvn/6/)

Comment: @NejcGalof give an example of what you want

Comment: My week start on saturday. So when I select date on week automatic select saturday. It's work. On #to datepicker select always friday. onSelect works, but not display good.

Comment: @NejcGalof it is highlighting `Friday 30` as today is `Friday 30`

Comment: Ah I see. always select 30.8